# Truncated Text on Select Menu for Android Phones

Tags: android, select-menu, longtext

[screenshot of problem](http://imgur.com/44G2JEH)

I am currently testing a website I am working on on Android devices.  I noticed that the text is getting cut off for the longer options on the select menu aka drop down menu.  I know that the text is lengthy but I would like users to be able to read the entire text. Is there a way to fix this? Perhaps make the text smaller on Android devices, let each option contain multiple lines so the entire text can be displayed? I would appreciate any guidance.

```
    <form name=\"service_menu\" action=\"javascript:document.location=document.service_menu.service.value\">
                                <select name=\"service\">

                                <option selected=\"selected\" value=\"lake-nona-orlando-services.php\">Select A Service</option>

                <option value=\"lake-nona-orlando-commercial-additions-remodeling.php\">Additions & Remodeling - Commercial</option>
                <option value=\"lake-nona-orlando-home-additions-remodeling.php\">Additions & Remodeling - Home</option>
                <option value=\"lake-nona-orlando-air-conditioning.php\">Air Conditioning & Heating</option>
                <option value=\"lake-nona-orlando-defense-attorney.php\">Attorney - Defense</option>
                <option value=\"lake-nona-orlando-family-attorney.php\">Attorney - Family</option>
        <option value=\"lake-nona-window-tinting-auto-home.php\">Window Tinting - Auto & Home</option>
                <option value=\"lake-nona-orlando-windows-doors.php\">Windows & Doors</option>
                <optgroup label=''></optgroup>
                                </select>
                                <input type=\"submit\" class=\"button-form\" value=\"Go\"/>
                                </form>
```

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. I've fixed it for iPhone with some kind of 'optgroup' hack but android isn't paying attention to what I've done. Have you found anything out??